# Como puedo hacer una conexión en laravel sin tener que usar el archivo database.php

Tags: php, base-de-datos, laravel-8

Necesito conectarme a diferentes bases de datos, pero necesito hacerlo directamente en la consulta sin tener que especificar la información de conexión en el archivo database.php de laravel, ¿si es posible?

Este es mi código:

```
public function prueba()
{
    try {
        $data  =   Mesa::on([
            'driver' => 'mysql',
            'url' => env('DATABASE_URL'),
            'host' => '127.0.0.1',
            'port' => '3306',
            'database' => 'mydatabase_laravel',
            'username' => 'root',
            'password' => '',
            'unix_socket' => env('DB_SOCKET', ''),
            'charset' => 'utf8mb4',
            'collation' => 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci'
        ])->get();
        return $data;
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        error_log($e);
        return Responses::errorHttpXWithoutErrors(500, 'Ocurrió un error al asignar las notas');
    }
}
```

Este es el error que me marca:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Hola Yeimer, bienvenido a Stack Overflow en español. Quizas [esta respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42199159/3791844) pueda ayudar. PD: podes realizar el [tour] así aprendes más sobre el funcionamiento del sitio y de paso ganar tu primer medalla. Saludos!